# Setting the same host address on different networks

Tags: networking, lan, ip-address, subnets

I have a set of devices to be deployed on different local networks which have to be configured without DHCP.

Every network has the same subnet mask and the gateway and the device in every network have always the same host portion of the address (e.g. XXX.XXX.XXX.9 for the gateway and XXX.XXX.XXX.11 for the device).

Is it possible to write a single `/etc/network/interfaces` file without knowing the network portion of the address so that the device will configure a static IP for itself with host portion XXX.XXX.XXX.11 and gateway XXX.XXX.XXX.9?

Comment: How should the device guess the missing parts of the IP? Are you looking for [RFC3927](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3927)?

Comment: We used to have the `divine` package in Debian but it is obsolete. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=387774 "Description: Automatic IP configuration detection for laptops
 Divine uses ARP requests to probe the current network
 and reconfigures networking based on its findings."